# How to derive the mean and variance of a two phase sample?

Tags: estimation, sampling

Suppose there are $N$ authors, and each author has writen $A_i$($i=1\dots  N$) articles. I want to estimate the average level of the authors by scoring the articles. the level of author $i$ is defined as the mean of the quality score of all his articles, that is $X_i = \frac{1}{A_i}\sum_{j=1}^{A_i} Q_{ij}$, where $X_i$ is the level of author $i$, and $Q_{ij}$ is the quality score of article $j$ of author $i$.

Since Both $N$ and $A_i$ are very large, it is impossible to score all the authors and all their articles, so I use the following method to estimate the average level of the authors:

1. randomly choose $K$ authors.
2. from each of the $K$ authors, randomly choose $n_i$ articles. the total number of the articles $M=\sum_{i=1}^{K}n_i$ is fixed.
3. use $Y=\frac{1}{K}\sum_{i=1}^{K}\frac{1}{n_i}\sum_{j=1}^{n_i}Q_{ij}$ as the estimator of the average level of all authors.

My question is:

1. Is $Y$ an unbiased estimation?
2. How to derive the variance of $Y$?
3. When $M$ is fixed, how to choose $K$ and $n_i$ to minimize the variance of $Y$?

EDIT:

As mentioned in StatsStudent's comment, this problem is a Two-Stage Cluster Sampling problem, but the purpose is a little different.

Here I want to estimate the mean of the primary units, i.e. the average level of all the authors, not the average score of all the articles. In a typical Two-Stage Cluster Sampling, $Y=\frac{1}{K}\sum_{i=1}^{K}\frac{1}{n_i}\sum_{j=1}^{n_i}Q_{ij}$ is a biased estimation of the mean score of all the articles, but it seems like an unbiased estimation of the mean level of all the authors.

Comment: What you are doing is a well-known and well-studied sampling methodology called Two-Stage Cluster Sampling, not Two Phase Sampling.  Any elementary textbook on sampling will detail the formulas for you.  I suggest the classic and timeless Sampling Techniques, 2nd Edition by William Gemmel Cochran.